# css how to center this content

Tags: html, css

I have made a fiddle for my problem.

This is it
http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/

This is the result of my code:
[image]

I need to do two things:

First, center all the content inside the div with the border. I mean this div `<div id="agentsLegend">`

Second, center the text to be in the center of the circle. the text exist in this code:

```
<span class="oneLegend">
    <div class="breakLegend oneAgentLegent"></div>
    Break
</span>
```

I tried:

```
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
```

but the content is not centered.

Comment: Look at this: No need to make all the hacks.
http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/
Add the CSS, to the element to cant verticaly centered, note that the parent of the element MUST have a specified height, can be done with jQuery or just CSS.

Comment: Element div not allowed as child of element span in this context.

Comment: you should turn your wrapped div into a iline tag , such as span or b or i or whatever wich is not a block and does have no meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `vertical-align` to    `.oneAgentLegent`  as well.

And eventually  set a line-height to `#agentsLegend`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/3/)**

```
#agentsLegend {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:38px;
    line-height:30px;/* tune baseline height here */
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.oneLegend {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.oneAgentLegent {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px; 
    display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;/* make this to vertical-align:middle to text aside */
}
```

---

To center your inline-boxe: use `text-align:center` on parent.

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/5/)**

```
body {
    text-align:center;/* parent of your box in fiddle demo */
}
```

---

edit , if you want to use display:table instead, add display:table-cell to span , so it easily vertical center content : http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/9/

Comment: please what is the changes you did? i couldn't find any

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli i did copy/paste code in answer with comments :)

Comment: please when I make the `font-size:20px;` inside the `.oneLegend`, the text is not centered with the circle anymore. could you tell me what to do please?

Comment: still the same. when i increase the line-height, both the text and the circle goes down

Comment: what do you think of using `margin-top:-4px;` in the circle?

Comment: why not, i just try to avoid negative margin as much as i can , but not more or less better than tuning average line-height :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done a few changes to the css. These should help you fix your issue.

1. Reduced the height and added padding top to #agentsLegend element.

   > height:28px; padding-top:9px;
2. Changed `vertical-align:middle;` to `vertical-align:top;` in .oneLegend element.
3. Added `line-height: 20px;` to .oneLeged element.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/8Kx8c/11/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DUgKb/19/

You cannot have a span wrapping a div. It was not working since a span is not a block element.

1. Add a wrapping div to center everything.

   ```
    .center {
      text-align: center;
     }
   ```
2. vertical align the icons

   ```
   #agentsLegend {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px;
   }

   .oneAgentLegent, .oneLegend {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of `vertical-align` on the children with `line-height` set on the parent for the vertical aligning, and setting `display:table;` and `margin:0 auto` on the parent to center horizontally.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/4/)

CSS

```
#agentsLegend {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px;
    line-height:38px;/* <-- vertical alignment */
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    display:table; /* <-- horizontal alignment */
    margin:0 auto; /* <-- horizontal alignment */
}
.oneLegend {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;/* <-- vertical alignment */
}
.oneAgentLegent {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align:-10%;/* <-- vertical alignment */
    display:inline-block;
}
.agent-table-wrap td.breakAgentClass, .breakLegend {
    background: #6b4e30;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzZiNGUzMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM5OTg5NzIiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6b4e30 0%, #998972 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6b4e30), color-stop(100%, #998972));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6b4e30 0%, #998972 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6b4e30 0%, #998972 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6b4e30 0%, #998972 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6b4e30 0%, #998972 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b4e30', endColorstr='#998972', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff;
}
.agent-table-wrap td.idelAgentClass, .idelLegent {
    background: #fcda19;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcda19 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcda19), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcda19 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcda19 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcda19 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcda19 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcda19', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-8 */
    color: #333;
}
.agent-table-wrap td.pauseAgentClass, .pauseLegend {
    background: #1283b7;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1283b7 0%, #bad1e2 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1283b7), color-stop(100%, #bad1e2));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1283b7 0%, #bad1e2 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1283b7 0%, #bad1e2 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1283b7 0%, #bad1e2 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1283b7 0%, #bad1e2 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1283b7', endColorstr='#bad1e2', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff;
}
.agent-table-wrap td.talkingAgentClass, .talkingLegend {
    background: #4ea51c;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ea51c 0%, #aae579 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4ea51c), color-stop(100%, #aae579));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ea51c 0%, #aae579 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ea51c 0%, #aae579 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ea51c 0%, #aae579 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4ea51c 0%, #aae579 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4ea51c', endColorstr='#aae579', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff;
}
.agent-table-wrap td.voicemailAgentClass, .voiceMailLegend {
    background: #8a38aa;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a38aa 4%, #db95f4 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(4%, #8a38aa), color-stop(100%, #db95f4));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a38aa 4%, #db95f4 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a38aa 4%, #db95f4 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a38aa 4%, #db95f4 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a38aa 4%, #db95f4 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a38aa', endColorstr='#db95f4', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: if you use display:table, keep going with table-cell, no need then to tune with negative vertical-align inside content : http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/9/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change some properties like :

```
#agentsLegend {
  display: table;   
}
.oneLegend {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add only `line-height:38px;` on `#agentsLegend` and `vertical-align:middle;` on class `oneLegend`

```
#agentsLegend {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:38px;
    line-height:38px; /*Addded line*/
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.oneLegend {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle; /*Addded line*/
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kx8c/10/) link.